# Updated: Store the logged in attempts in database using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, login-attempts

I try to store the logged in attempts in the database, but it's not working. The loginAttempt columns is not updating. Also, I want to count the login attempts and block the user after 3 attempts.

How to fix this?

Here's the script:

```
session_start();
$loginDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$Error ="";
$successMessage ="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ( !( $_POST['cnumber'] == "" && $_POST['password'] == "")){
    $cnumber=$_POST['cnumber'];
    $password= sha1($_POST['password']);
    $cnumber = filter_var($cnumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if (filter_var($cnumber, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","password","login");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE contractNumber='$cnumber' AND password='$password'");
$data = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($data==1){
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$cnumber;
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `homecre1_testemailCheck`.`Logs`(`contractNumber`, `lastLogin`) VALUES ('$cnumber', '$loginDate')");
    header('Location: profile.php');
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Logs SET loginAttempt = loginAttempt+1 WHERE contractNumber = '$cnumber'");
} 
    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    $Error ="Invalid Contract Number.";
 }
} else {
    $Error ="Contract Number or Password is Empty.";
}
```

Here's my database structure:

```
Users - table
id -PK
contractNumber
email
password

Logs - table
userId
contractNumber
lastLogin
loginAttempt
```

Comment: it is because you didnt insert `contarct_number` along with `login`.`Users`

Comment: even i insert the contract number still its not saving

Comment: I notice you have both contARct_number and contractNumber. What is the actual field spelling and capitalization?

Comment: @LuthandoLoot login.Users is databasename.tablename

Comment: @kojow7 contractNumber is the correct. I correct it now but still its not storing in my table

Comment: i noticed now you changed your query to update `Logs` table instead of `Users`. did you test after that change to see if it is working?

Comment: Yes I tested it, but the Logs table is not updating/inserting values

Comment: please print your first query and see if it is adding the right values `echo "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE contractNumber='$cnumber' AND password='$password'"`. take the printed query and test it in your actual database

Comment: Yes, it display the right values. I can login using contractnumber and password that stored in the database

Answer (score 2):

Your update query is missing `SET` and column `contarct_number` might be wrong: Your query should be like:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Logs SET loginAttempt = loginAttempt+1   
WHERE contractNumber = '$cnumber'");
```

Comment: what happen if multiple user can login ? if he didnot save the the last login against the user. ?

Comment: @Noman what are you talking about? i am just fixing the incorrect query syntax

Comment: still the login attempts is not saving